# My laptop was designed for Windows 7 and has issues with Windows 10. What should I do?

Tags: linux, windows-7, windows, drivers, bootloader

I have bought my laptop in 2011, when Microsoft Windows 7 was latest desktop Windows OS.

Today, Windows 7 is dead. There is no reason of installing it for four months.

I have attempted to install Windows 8.1 and 10.

Windows 10 USB didn't support EFI because of incorrect partitioning.

Windows 8.1 stuck in reboot loop with installation error message, so I had to use legacy boot.

When installed with legacy boot, both Windows 8.1 and 10 had screen shaking issue (but I forgot to install drivers, because they are labeled 'for Windows 7'). SD card reader didn't work.

I have installed Windows 7. It works in EFI mode (but bootloader needs to be fixed from installation media), but it needs Wi‐Fi drivers found on DVD‐ROM. IIRC SD card reader worked in Windows 7, but this time it asked me to format SD card, which I didn't do.

On GNU/Linux, SD card reader is working better than on Windows 10, but still cannot read SD cards. I don't know how to install bootloader *correctly*, because when boot entry is created, system reboots, so it is installed to fallback path.

What should I do?

Comment: For your driver issues in W10.....https://superuser.com/questions/951021/which-drivers-should-i-use-on-windows-10-when-only-drivers-for-windows-7-and-8-1?rq=1

Comment: @JW0914 this is the comment section, so Tetsujin made a comment not an answer.

Comment: What make and model laptop?

Comment: @davidgo, SAMSUNG RV508 (NP-RV508-A02UA).

Answer (score 0):

*Any motherboard with UEFI firmware should not have Windows installed in Legacy Mode, as Secure Boot protects the Windows bootloader.*

---

Before installing Windows, ensure Secure Boot is enabled in the UEFI Firmware and Legacy Mode is disabled.

1. Download the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

   - Choose the option to install on another PC so that it creates an ISO.
2. Download the portable version of [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create a bootable USB

   1. **Device:** USB drive

      - *You will format the USB drive, so backup any data on it you want to save*
   2. **Boot Selection:** `Windows.iso`
   3. **Image Option:** Standard Windows Installation
   4. **Partition Scheme:** GPT
   5. **Target System:** UEFI (non CSM)
   6. **File System:** Large FAT32 (Default)
   7. Disable Exclusive Drive Locking via **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>**, then *Start*
3. During POST, press the key that loads the PC boot menu and choose the EFI USB from the list
4. Go through Windows Setup, ensuring you're connected to the internet via an ethernet cable
5. **Once Windows OOBE begins** *(**O**ut **O**f **B**ox **E**xperience requires user input)***:**

   1. Disconnect ethernet cable and *DO NOT* setup WiFi
   2. For the user account, choose *Local User*

      - *This allows your user account to have a sane name, instead of your email, and later, after OEM CPU drivers have been installed, you can then convert the Local account to a Mircosoft online account via Settings.*
6. **Once at the Windows Desktop:**

   1. Install ***only*** the CPU drivers (Chipset, IMEI, etc. *in that order*), rebooting after each driver install.

      - *These are downloaded from the PC manufacturer's website, and are vital to the PC, as Windows Update does not install CPU drivers. 
         **These must be installed prior to Windows Updates and any other software or drivers**.*
   2. Once all CPU drivers have been installed, reconnect PC to the internet and run Windows Update.

      1. Reboot whenever Windows Update requests to and again after all updates have been installed.
      2. Once rebooted, re-run Windows Update

         - *Repeat 6.2.1 & 6.2.2 until Windows Update shows no more available updates*
         - *Windows Update will install all required drivers (excl. CPU drivers), however, there may be a couple it can't find (Renesas drivers are notorious for this). You'll need to manually download these from each manufacture's website(s).*
   3. Convert your Local user account to an online Microsoft account via: 
       *Settings* > *Accounts* > *Your Info* - *Sign in with a Microsoft Account*
   4. Install software
   5. I always recommend moving user folders *(`%UserProfile%\Contacts`, etc.)* to a partition other than `C:`

      1. Right-click on User folders > *Properties*
      2. *Location* > New path *(i.e. `D:\User\Contacts`, etc.)* > *OK*

Comment: My laptop does not support Secure Boot. Also, someone said me that my SD card is using non‐standard protocol and such devices are broken starting from Windows 8.

Comment: The steps as given will still work, and if they don't, then in Rufus select _MBR_ for _Partition Scheme_ and _BIOS (or UEFI-CSM)_ for _Target System_.  As to your card reader, the manufacturer _(of the card reader, not the PC)_ will likely have the most up to date drivers on their site